# Parsing a semicolon-delimited string to extract values

Tags: php, string, url, url-routing, url-parameters

I need to extract some values from a URL, and then use these values to send an email.

Thanks to the kind of help on some others on here, I have nearly nailed it. The problem I am having is is that the url appendages look like this

```
?SessionID=582506&Note=joe@bloggs.com;joe bloggs;111.111.111.111&Status=203&Operator=
```

As you might have noticed the email address, name, amount and ip address are all stored in the note variable, separated by a semicolon.

Is there a way to parse the note value and extract the data (that is limited by semicolons) from it as separate quantities that I can then use in compiling an email?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the data from the `Note` parameter, then split the value at semicolon (with e.g. [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)) and you can reach each part of the value in the resulting array.

```
$note = $_GET["Note"];
$note_parts = explode(";", $note);

$email = $note_parts[0];
$name = $note_parts[1];
$addr = $note_parts[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$notes = explode(';', $_GET['Note']);
var_dump($notes);
```

One issue I see is that you claimed to have an amount in the string, but there is no amount in your expample url.  You have to get at the individual components of the Note positionally ($notes[0], $notes[1], etc.) or you'd have to roll something more complicated if these items can be in various positions inside the Note= parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right

```
$note = $_GET['note'];
$arr = explode(";", $note);
```

And in $arr you have all your attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode and list. for global `$_GET['Note'];`

```
<?php

list($mail,$name,$ip) = explode(';',$_GET['Note']);
```

if you want to parse the url directly 
[parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str)  will help you.

```
<?php
    parse_str("SessionID=582506&Note=joe@bloggs.com;joe bloggs;111.111.111.111&Status=203&Operator=",$array);
    var_dump($array);
/*
array(4) {
  ["SessionID"]=>
  string(6) "582506"
  ["Note"]=>
  string(41) "joe@bloggs.com;joe bloggs;111.111.111.111"
  ["Status"]=>
  string(3) "203"
  ["Operator"]=>
  string(0) ""
}*/
```

Comment: thanks for that - i know how to get each value - what i am struggling with is separating the note down into its constituent parts - email, name, ip, amount. any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the $_GET super global to retrive the values from a URL e.g.

```
$sessid = $_GET["SessionID"]; # Although this seems pointless
                              # when you can use session_id()
$note = $_GET["Note"];
$status = $_GET["Status"];
$operator = $_GET["Operator"];
```

A better way still, would be to use the pre-built function in PHP to parse a url:

```
$url = "http://mysite.com/index.php?"
       ."SessionID=582506&Note=joe@bloggs.com;"
       ."joe bloggs;111.111.111.111&Status=203&Operator=";
$arrayOfURL = parse_url($url); # Returns an associative array of all URL components
print_r($arrayOfURL);
```

Reference sheet for you:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

As for breaking up a String into its pieces separated by a delimiter, use the explode($delimiter, $stringToExplode) function.
Tutorial on this: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/php-string-explode.php

Comment: thanks for that - i know how to get each value - what i am struggling with is separating the note down into its constituent parts - email, name, ip, amount. any ideas on that?

Comment: @user1332723 updated my answer for the second part to your question

Answer (score 0):

```
$note  = $_GET["Note"];
$notes = explode(";", $note);

echo $notes[0]; // joe@bloggs.com
echo $notes[1]; // joe bloggs
echo $notes[2]; // 111.111.111.111
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
        function parseQueryString($str) 
        { 
            $op = array(); 
            $pairs = explode("&", $str); 
            foreach ($pairs as $pair) 
            { 
                list($k, $v) = array_map("urldecode", explode("=", $pair)); 
                $op[$k] = $v; 
            } 
            return $op; 
        }

        $str = "SessionID=582506&Note=joe@bloggs.com;joe bloggs;111.111.111.111&Status=203";

        $p = parse_url($str);
        $s = parseQueryString($p['path']);

        print_r($s);
?>
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [SessionID] => 582506
    [Note] => joe@bloggs.com;joe bloggs;111.111.111.111
    [Status] => 203
)
```

**As for the `Note` variable :**

```
<?php
     $notes = explode(";", $s['Note']);

     $email = $notes[0];
     $name = $notes[1];
     $ipaddress = $notes[2];
?>
```